# Navigation stack becomes unusable after canceling iOS 7 back swipe gesture

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am running into an issue where my navigation controller becomes unusable after initiating then canceling the new iOS 7 back swipe gesture.

Some relevant information:

- My app has a home page with various activity pages.
- The home page hides the navigation bar in viewWillAppear
- The home page un-hides the navigation bar in viewWillDisappear

  ```
  -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];

      // Let's hide the navbar when we show the home view
      [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
      …
  }

  -(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
  {
      [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

      // Let's hide the navbar when we show the home view
      [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
  }
  ```

When a user taps a activity icon on the home page the view controller for the activity is pushed onto the stack.

If a user starts to use the new back swipe gesture in iOS but then stops the gesture (i.e. decides not to go back) everything looks ok.  However, if a user causes another view controller to get pushed on the nav stack the nag bar then becomes unusable and the user can not navigate back from the current view controller.

**Notes**

- It only happens when I show/hide the navigation bar
- I can still slowly perform the back gesture and everything will work fine as long as I don't cancel the gesture
- The nav bar seems like it will work but hitting the back button doesn't pop the view controller.

Comment: While not the best solution, I got around this issue by just disabling the swipe gesture control for transitions when I hide and show the nav bar:
`self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  For the time being I've just disabled the swipe for back feature.  I didn't want it to be confusing to the user; not knowing when/why the swipe worked in some areas and not others.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not sure if you already resolved this but I'm facing the same issue but with one difference. The navigation stack only messes up if I setAnimated to NO.

So this works:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
...
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

but this doesn't:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
...
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

If you really want animated to be NO for whatever reason, one work around is to set alpha to 0/1 instead of hiding/unhiding the NavigationBar:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.0f;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setAlpha:1.0f];
}
```

The downside is that there's no nice slide-to-pop transition animation. If you did find a better way, do let us know.

**UPDATE**: This is now old but I solved my issue by not ensuring that whatever state is changed in current view's viewWillDisappear, is restored in viewWillAppear. Don't tear down things in viewWillDisappear that you can't setup again.

This is what happens when you cancel the pop animation:

---

1. Current viewWillDisappear
2. New viewWillAppear
3. [cancelled... reverses]
4. New viewWillDisappear
5. New viewDidDisappear
6. Current viewWillAppear
7. Current viewDidAppear

---

I guess in this brave new world, viewWillDisappear/viewWillAppear does not always mean view "will" disappear/appear :)

Comment: This fixes the issue, but on the downside, the status bar still thinks the navigation controller is present behind it. If the navigation controller is dark and the main view contents are light, status bar text is white (on light/white background).

If navigation bar is hidden with setNavigationBarHidden, status bar text properly switches black on the light background.

Comment: Your original suggestions work, but I don't understand what your update means. Why would `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];` restore state but `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];` wouldn't?

Comment: @Tree Hugger - Is the word "not" a *mistake* in "UPDATE: This is now old but I solved my issue by *not* ensuring ..."?  Seems like you *do* want to ensure, but as written, you are saying you *don't* want to ensure...

Answer (score 3):

I think my solution may help you.

Let's assume that the class of your homepage view controller is HomePageViewController(class name), and the activity view controller is called ActivityViewController(class name, too)

First, in your HomePageViewController's viewWillAppear:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Secondly, in your ActivityViewController, add these codes:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //trick to fix navigationbar disappear problem that when UIScreenEdgePanGesture is happening.
    if ([self.navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[HomePageViewController class]]) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    } else {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and after searching around, it looks like you can't get a notification if the gesture is cancelled.  There is no `-shouldCancel` on the gesture recognizer delegate, and there is no `-willReshowViewController` on the navigation controller.  So I have the view controller that needs the navigation bar shown (i.e. the controller that is being cancelled on) set `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO` in `-viewWillAppear`.  That way when the gesture is cancelled and `-viewWillAppear` is called, the navigation bar will be unhidden again.  As far as I can tell, this is the only way to have both the swipe-back gesture and shown/hidden navigation bars without a problem when cancelling the gesture.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily work - `viewWillAppear` isn't called when the gesture is canceled, in my experience. (iOS 11)

Answer (score 1):

Its will help you to avoid freezing the app.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
       didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animate
{
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)])
    {
        if (self.navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1)
        {
            self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by using `animated: true` in `viewWillAppear` and `animated: false` in `viewWillDisappear` of the 2nd view controller