# How to hide Navigation Bar without losing slide-back ability

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a UITableView and it has a nav bar(got from UINavigationViewController), it's able to go back by sliding back using a finger.

I tried to hide the nav bar but keep the slide-back ability, code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

This successfully hid the nav bar, however, I can no longer slide back to the last screen either.

Is there any way to hide the nav bar but keep the slide-back ability?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // hide nav bar
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    // enable slide-back
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    }
}


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

And in .h file, conform to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

Comment: It is working fine! Instead of setting **setNavigationBarHidden:YES**, in a Embed In > Navigation Controller then select _UINavigationController_ and  uncheck **Shows Navigation Bar**. By unchecking that, hiding navigation bar code can be removed.

Answer (score 66):

Tested with Swift 2 the solution of @gabbler, if you use

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
```

Swift 3.0

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

instead of

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

the swipe back gesture works like a charm!

Comment: For some amazingly werid and beautiful reason this actually works. Might it be a bug in UIKit?

Comment: Note that animating this to be **system-smooth** in `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:` to disable a `UINavigationBar` in a particular `UIViewController` inside a `UINavigationController` can be a really good challenge, especially when doing `viewWillDisappear:`. For that particular case, we use `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` but this also disables the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`. In my particular case, I don't do what this answer says because it's hard and pretty much buggy to animate this property.

Comment: `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true` does not hide the nav bar in iOS 11/Swift 4.x; only `self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true` does.

Comment: @EvanR, on my device and simulator (latest iOS - 11.3) works fine.

Comment: I can confirm that it's still working on iOS 11.4 and Swift 4.x.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

or add this line in viewWillAppear:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

It seems the interaction is not effective, adding this line and make the view controller conforms to the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol will make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to include:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

And:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

And:

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    }
```

It should appear like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
            self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
        }
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it assigns the delegate to itself, but it doesn't implement the gestureRecognizerShouldBegin method. I've added the solution that works for me. Thank you for your effort, I appreciate it.

Comment: @ZinanXing, haha I added that to my code and then I saw where you said you found a solution...

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.x and iOS 11.4.**

The @gabbler solution is still working. Idk, looks like this is a UIKit bug, but..

Just use:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Only solution that worked for me on iOS 12 swift 4.2! 

Answer (score 2):

Zinan Xings solution in Swift 4.2 (Please give him upvote!):

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for Xamarin Forms i was Struggle with this so first don't NavigationRenderer you'll get NavigationController null instead use PageRenderer:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(ContentPageRenderer))]
namespace sample
{
    class ContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

            var navctrl = this.ViewController.NavigationController;
            navctrl.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Delegate = new UIGestureRecognizerDelegate();
            navctrl.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code for Swift 5:

```
private func setupNavController() {
            
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)     
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
    if let interactivePopGestureRecognizer = navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer {
        self.tableView.panGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: interactivePopGestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

I have a UIViewController which contains a UITableView inside. This code helps you keep the smooth transition when you swipe back or press the back button. Call this function in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

If hiding the the navigation bar did't help, try changing the rect of the navigation bar and see?

navBarBgFrame.origin.y = - navBarBgFrame.size.height;