# iOS UINavigationController push/pop cross horizontal cover animation

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

The pushed controller cross over current controller.

Results are as follows:
[image]
image 0

Actually, I have hook into this app, it use a subclass named MMUINavigationController, 
and I am sure current action is "pushViewController:animated:", it's the interface I hooked.

Tweak.xm: 
[image]
image 1

alertView:
[image]
image 2

how to make it ？

additional，standar animation:

[image]

image 3

navigation bar of pushed controller

[image: 5]

image 4

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DAN how to make it？

Comment: That looks to me like a standard IOS push animation

Comment: @DAN take attention to the title bar

Comment: The pushed view controller has no navigation bar, maybe that's confusing you

Comment: @DAN you mean.. the pushed controller hide it's navigation bar before pushed？？

Comment: Hide the navigation controller bar and let each view controller decide whether to show or not its own navigation bar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106318/discussion-between-ccnyou-and-dan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution:

1. hide the navigation bar of the navigation controller
2. add a navigation bar to the root view controller of the navigation controller
3. restore the swipe to back gesture to the navigation controller

For the last point you can add a pan gesture recognizer (suggested) or simply set the interactivePopGestureRecognizer's delegate of the navigation controller to nil:

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil;
```

but please refer to this discussion for its implications: [No Swipe Back when hiding Navigation Bar in UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710258/no-swipe-back-when-hiding-navigation-bar-in-uinavigationcontroller)

**EDIT:**

Working solution which fulfills the requirements: just setting the `navigationBarHidden` in the `viewWillAppear` does the magic.

I've setup a sample demo here: https://github.com/ldantona/NavigationBarExample

**EDIT 2:**

Just found this library, could it be of any help?
https://github.com/MoZhouqi/KMNavigationBarTransition

> The library can capture the background style of the navigation bar in
>   the disappearing view controller when pushing, and when you pop back
>   to the view controller, the navigation bar will restore the previous
>   style, so you don't need to consider the background style after
>   popping. And you also don't need to consider it after pushing, because
>   it is the view controller to be pushed that needs to be considered.

Hope it helps

Comment: In image 3, left controller share one navigation bar with pushed controller. Can this solution make it ?

Comment: No, as far as I know with this solution you have to manually add a navigation bar to each view controller

Comment: such a sadly story

Comment: see image 1, the left back button "< 返回" also have gradient effect. Slowly change to "< 微信"

Comment: actually it works exactly like that (I've updated the sample project to show it between the first two view controllers)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106377/discussion-between-dan-and-ccnyou).

Comment: Maybe it use a fake navigationBar on pop and set backgroundImage of poping navigationBar to clear color. See image of discuss.