# Swift hide the navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am working on a project and want to hide the navigation bar in my App. I have already found some code in the web to hide the bar, but always when I hide it, the swipe back function disables. So I don't want to have the navigation bar, but I want to have the swipe back function.

I have already tried this code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

And this code here too:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

And so on...

Comment: Have you set     self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true       For UIViewController??

Comment: Yes I have tried it, but I still does not work.

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60999039/14733292

Comment: Thank u very much. It is working now

Answer (score 1):

when you hide nav bar swipe to go back won't work. Maybe you want totally transparent nav bar which I suggest to you, because you can constraint views with safe area like that and you will have swipe to go back.

```
    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navBarAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
    navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
    navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title? = "Back"
```