# NavigationBar back button strange behavior and not working

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I have encountered a strange behavior on the back button of a navigation bar. I will try my best to describe with with screenshots(through links, as I cant not upload yet)

Here is the first screen, or the parent view with the navigation bar hidden: [Screen 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BygKBpMi0IWbd3hudlFWcXlGQlZkMmd4emxoSmF3cHRVangw/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the code for first screen:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

This is my code for pushing the view controller:

```
var second = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("As_ThirdViewControllerID") as! As_ThirdViewController!

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(second, animated: true)
```

When you click the last tab bar button, it will bring you to a second screen: [Screen 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BygKBpMi0IWbR0ZsRTRYbUI1b09iME5RVUVGdWl3ZnpQZFZB/view?usp=sharing)

Same code as first screen, only, the navigation bar is NOT hidden

Now, in that second screen, you can see a BUTTON...when you click the button you will be brought to the third and last screen:
[Screen 3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BygKBpMi0IWbQUtfOTFVWFk1cjR1aU5TZ0hfT1pxNk5IMEZn/view?usp=sharing)

Same code as first screen, only, the navigation bar is NOT hidden

THE STRANGE BEHAVIOR:
When I swipe going back(third screen -> second -> parent) -- ITS WORKING..
When I press back button from the THIRD and last screen --> it looks like this:
[Screen 4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BygKBpMi0IWbbFBmM3JZX2lNaTY0M0piNjZ6OW9XeWY0TVZj/view?usp=sharing)
-- NOT WORKING, not going back to the previous screen...the word "back"  suddenly goes away from the arrow

I don't have a lot of codes in my classes as of now as I am just starting and formulating the design, so I could not figure out what's wrong with my program..

Comment: Make the links to be accessed by everyone, without having to request access.

Comment: HI, sorry for that, I already made the links  public..

Comment: I made the tag objective c to attract attention from people who know how objective C, maybe they already encountered this in the past.. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Put the code, That you use to pop back ?

Comment: Hello, I do not have any code to pop back, the back button goes with the navigation bar, so it makes me confused as to why it would behave that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you have navigationController stack and navigationBar stack mismatch.

Try adding custom button and selector then pop using

```
self.navigationController.popViewController(viewController);
```

Comment: The mismatch happens because you don't have navigation bar button on one VC and have on others.

Comment: Why did you post the question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218716/navigation-button-strange-behavior-not-working-with-video (Another one)

Comment: Post your complete code or host it somewhere. I have tried your scenario and unable to reproduce the problem. It's working fine for me.

Comment: You should have edited your original question. You may receive lots of downvotes by doing so.

Comment: Noted, I will edit it, but, what do you think is the problem with my navigation controller/bar? Have you seen the other post?

Comment: I have tried pushing popping with gestures also but unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you watched my video? At the second screen, try swiping back..but dont continue it and just stay at the second view controller half way through swiping

Answer (score 0):

I could not edit my own post, the site says it has unformatted codes, when all I have added was a sentence below the post that had codes in it before I even edited it. I don't what happened.

But here's what I did:

It appears this is a bug in iOS, I saw a similar post and no one has solved the problem itself:

[Navigation stack becomes unusable after canceling iOS 7 back swipe gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915657/navigation-stack-becomes-unusable-after-canceling-ios-7-back-swipe-gesture)

I just followed the suggestion and disabled the interactivePopGestureRecognizer